# How to show limited number of items in a list based on lines consumed by li

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, bulletedlist

I am using a bulleted list to show only limited number of items without scrollbar in 'UL' on page loads and then on click of a 'more' button, I want to show the rest of item with scrollbar in `UL`, for that purpose, I have use following code that works fine:

```
<body onload="resetPops();">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="info2-wrapper">
    <div class="info2">
        <asp:BulletedList ID="listACB" runat="server" />
        <%  const Int16 numACB = 2;
            if (listACB.Items.Count > numACB)
            {
        %>
        <div class="more">
            <% =(listACB.Items.Count - numACB) %>
            more</div>
        <div class="less">
            Collapse</div>
        <% } %>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

in code behid, I bind the list as:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listACB.DataSource = GetCategoryBoxItems();
        listACB.DataBind();
        foreach (ListItem item in listACB.Items)
        {
            item.Attributes.Add("class", "detail bullet");
        }
    }

    private object GetCategoryBoxItems()
    {
        return new List<String>
        {
            "abc",
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam cursus. Morbi ut mi. ",
            "pqr",
            "xyz",
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit am"
        };
    }
```

JS code is like:

```
function resetPops() {
        $('.info2, .info2 ul').removeClass('expanded');
        $('.more').show();
        $('.less').hide();
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.info2 .more').click(function () {
            resetPops();
            $('.info2, .info2 ul').addClass('expanded');
            $('.more, .less').toggle();
        });
        $('.info2 .less').click(function () {
            $('.expanded').scrollTop(0);
            resetPops();
        });
    });
```

This code is working good for the number of items in the list, but problem is that when any list item is getting into more than one lines, last items are not visible.(as height of ul is fixed).This scenario comes when we see it on lower resolution, in this case, few list items get into more than one line and due to which last items are not visible.

For example, as shown below, 2nd item gets into two line causing 5th list item to be hidden:

```
•   abc
•   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer 
    adipiscing elit. Nam cursus. Morbi ut mi.
•   pqr
•   xyz
•   Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
```

I am facing this issue because I have have handled this based of number of list items  only not the number of lines in the `UL`. So how can I handle this scenario that `more` button is shown based on number of line in the `UL` and number of list item both?

Comment: you don't want `overflow:scroll;` ?

Comment: @rps, Yes, I dont want `overflow:scroll;` in first case when I am showing limited number of listitems, but onclick of 'more' button, `overflow:scroll;` is allowed to show many items in fixed height.

Comment: then the fixed height is not of the `ul` but of the `li`, if `overflow:scroll;` is allowed then no matter what you should be able to see lists via scrolling!

Comment: @rps, I can not understand your last comment, but my simple question is that how can I put logic to show items based on number of lines in `li` not number of `li`? or is there any better approach I can follow?

Comment: _ based on number of lines in li_ doesn't sound foolproof to me (there may be `\n` too in there instead of lines with actual words) , My question was what is restricting you from seeing all the lines inside `li` ?? I doubt that it is the fixed height of `li` itself and no `ul`, hope you got what I meant.

Comment: @rps , it is `overflow:hidden` and `overflow:auto` css style on `ul` is used to show hide the list item. So, `overflow:hidden` on `ul` is restricting me to see that rest of item. thats fine as per requirements. So, what can I do to show only few `li` on load without scrolling in `ul` and rest `li` can be shown on click of a 'more' button by scrolling in `ul`.

Comment: yes, you can!! remove `overflow:hidden` though, you are using jquery right? use `$('li:lt(4)').show()` to show first 3 `li` then you can change it to `$('li:lt(8)').show()` later on to show more elements!!!

Comment: @rps, I can use jq's show/hide, but in that case how will i calculate number of li to fit in that fixed height container?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34894/discussion-between-rps-and-sanjeev-rai)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the logic to find the number of items after which I can show that 'more' button. Actually I have calculated total number of items after which I can show more button based on its height and when total height of `lis` exceeds height of `ul` then I can show that 'more' button, as:

```
getTotalHeight = function () {
var Visibleitemsheight = 0;
var lastindex = 0;
var totalItems = 5; //five items height is 80 that is fixed
var totalheight = 80;//height is 80 that is fixed for ul
var items = $('.info2 ul li');
items.each(function (index) {
    Visibleitemsheight += $(this).height();
    lastindex = index;
    if (Visibleitemsheight >= totalheight) {
        return false;
    }
});
lastindex++;
if (Visibleitemsheight >= totalheight) {
    if (lastindex < items.length) {
        $('.more').show();
        $('.more').text((items.length - lastindex) + " more items");
    }
    else if (lastindex == items.length) {
        if (Visibleitemsheight > totalheight) {
            $('.more').show();
            $('.more').text("more...");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

For now its working fine, Please suggest if there is any better approach. thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XTgvk/)

```
$('li:gt(2)').hide();
$('input').click(function(){
$('li:gt(2)').show();
$('li:gt(4)').hide();
});
```

Comment: my actual problem will not be solved by thi. How can I decide the number of items to show hide i.e. you have taken '2' in ur example.

Comment: what about the width of the container? is that fixed too?

Comment: have you tries `li { white-space: nowrap; }` &